# Fonts on Certain Web Pages jagged and blocky on XP yet fine in Windows7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, fonts

This site for example: http://www.cultbox.co.uk/reviews/episodes/778-twenty-twelve-episode-3-review

Which has this CSS - http://www.cultbox.co.uk/style.css

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    background: #D3D8E1;
}
```

I think I first saw this problem on Tech Republic.

Also is it possible to find out which Font the browser chose to render in?

Comment: You have to tell us what browser(s) you are using.

Comment: It makes no difference which browser I use, only which operating system.

Comment: I'll modify the above statement slightly whilst using Internet Explorer, and Chrome the text looks identically rubbish.  In Safari the text is identical if you leave font smoothing to "Windows Standard", however other settings result in smooth text, Firefox always has smooth text.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 under Windows 7 uses the new DirectWrite API, which can make some font/size combinations look terrible.  The solution (if I remember correctly) is to use a size that equates to a whole pixel value.

These links may provide more insight:
[Line One](https://web.archive.org/web/20121127203123/http://allcreatives.net:80/2009/12/05/smoother-font-face-embedding-in-ie-7-8/)
[Link Two](https://web.archive.org/web/20151003025623/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/06/29/ie9-cleartype-improved-clarity-for-tahoma-verdana-and-arial-fonts-fuzzy-blurry.aspx)

Comment: The problem is the reverse tho